# Cleaning headers in imported pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Having imported a series of csv and xls files, using the header in the file. I've noticed that these headers aren't clean, so that when i call them i get an error returned saying there's no such attribute. What i'm looking to do is something similar to this;

Use the built in function to create list of imported headers

```
currentheaders = list(df.columns.values)
```

Clean that list (this is the part i'm stuck on)

```
cleanedheaders = str.strip or regex equivalent
```

Apply that list as new headers

```
df.columns = ['cleanedheaders']
```

Strip doesn't work on lists and regex wants to be a data frame, is there an equivalent function for a list?

Comment: Please define "aren't clean". And please provide some executable bit of code and data; this might help getting answers.

Comment: Most probably you have problems not only with headers, but also with the data. So you should try to find appropriate value for the `sep` parameter.

Comment: If you just want to strip your column names: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: Thank you again Max, the data was clean but various extra spaces typed in after each header string. Your method is effective and elegant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A compact and quick way would be

```
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns.values.tolist()]
```

---

If you wanted to use `DataFrame.rename()` then you would in fact need to call it like that:

```
df.rename(columns={c: c.strip() for c in df.columns.values.tolist()}, inplace=True)
```

---

or you can of course use the also compact and quick (borrowed by MaxU):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

---

> Keep in mind none of the above solutions will work if ANY of the column names are in fact not a string.

If any of the column names is not a string, then ideally you would turn them all to strings, this would work:

```
df.columns = [str(i) for i in df.columns.values.tolist()]
```

or if you didn't want to turn column names to strings - for some good reason I hope - then you would have to do the following:

```
df.rename(columns={c: c.strip() for c in df.columns.values.tolist() 
                      if c not in [<list of columns not strings>]}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Thanos, they are thankfully all strings so Maxs' method worked

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
columns = {c: c.strip() for c in df.columns} # or any cleaning
df.rename(columns, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will strip all elements in a list:

```
list = [' test1', '   test2  ']
print [l.strip() for l in list]
```

Result:

> ['test1', 'test2']